# How to make a div show when HTML5 video player is paused?

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to get a div to show when an HTML5 video player is paused.

Comment: You can add your own answer to this post if you managed to solve this yourself... It's quite hard to read code in comments here...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to detect the `pause` event triggered by the video element.

Something like this should work for you:

```
var vid = document.getElementById( 'your_video_element_id' );
vid.addEventListener( 'pause', on_pause ); 
function on_pause( e ){
  // handle pause event - ie. show your div element
}
```

Comment: do you know how i set a delay on this "show div when video is paused" ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this,

```
function playPause(){
if(vid.paused){
    vid.play();
    playbtn.style.background = "url(pause.png)";
    pausebox.style.display = "none";
} else {
    vid.pause();
    playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png)";
    pausebox.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, video elements do not have any relevant attributes, however I would consider using the onclick attribute. You could do something like:

```
<video onclick="showDiv()">
  ...
</video>


<script>
  function showDiv(){
    //Use jQuery or basic javascript to hide/show the div element
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How would one differentiate between "click to play" and "click to pause"?

Comment: Select the video in jQuery and use .paused

    var video = $('selector').children('video');

    var videoElement = video.get(0);

    if (videoElement.paused) {...}

Comment: Ok... so why is this information not in your answer? That's kind of the important part...no? :)